# auto logout of facebook like plugin

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have created a html page with a facebook like box

```
<div class="fb-like-box"  data-href="http://www.facebook.com/pagelink" data-width="600" data-height="500" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="true" data-header="false" data-stream="true" data-show-border="false">
</div>
```

and the facebook SDK :

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=225361034284579";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Now, I want people to walk into my store, like the page on ipad. and it should automatically log them out after 30 seconds or I should have a logout button beside the like button where they can click and logout.

How do I implement either of the two or both.

Comment: Why do you need that? Will you inform the user that they will be logged out of their account? otherwise this is against the Policy

Comment: yes Azad, i will have a text saying, you can click on logout or you will be automatically logged out

Comment: Do you authenticate the user with your app? if NOT there's no possible ways of doing this

Comment: how can I do that in a like box plugin ?

Comment: The `Like box plugin` can't logout users of their accounts ..

Comment: What other option do I have to implement a "facebook like option for people on a public computer and then an auto logout or atleast a logout button